# Quartz 2D Opaque Data Types

Tags: ios, core-graphics

> Quartz 2D Opaque Data Types
>
> The Quartz 2D API defines a variety of opaque data types in addition
> to graphics contexts. Because the API is part of the Core Graphics
> framework, the data types and the routines that operate on **them** use
> the CG prefix.
>
> **Quartz 2D creates objects from opaque data types that your application
> operates on to achieve a particular drawing output.** Figure 1-3 shows
> the sorts of results you can achieve when you apply drawing operations
> to three of the objects provided by Quartz 2D. For example:
>
> You can rotate and display a PDF page by creating a PDF page object,
> applying a rotation operation to the graphics context, and asking
> Quartz 2D to draw the page to a graphics context.
>
> You can draw a
> pattern by creating a pattern object, defining the shape that makes up
> the pattern, and setting up Quartz 2D to use the pattern as paint when
> it draws to a graphics context.
>
> You can fill an area with an axial or
> radial shading by creating a shading object, providing a function that
> determines the color at each point in the shading, and then asking
> Quartz 2D to use the shading as a fill color.

I am having trouble understanding this part of [apple reference guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html)

and specifically the things i have bold, like what "them" is refereed to?

And please clarify about opaque data type generally , not in c or c++ terms.

Thanks in advance,
Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase *opaque type* simply means a type that contains or references data that you're not supposed to look at, or even be able to look at. For example, Quartz provides the `CGContextRef` type. Functions are provided for creating, obtaining, manipulating, and releasing a graphics context using an instance of `CGContextRef`, but you can't look inside a `CGContextRef` and see what's inside. You can't reasonably use or change a context without using the functions provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, but the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type  definition says " In computer science, an opaque data type is a data type that is incompletely defined in an interface, so that its values can only be manipulated by calling subroutines that have access to the missing information. The concrete representation of the type is hidden from its users. ". What they mean by incomplete? is this same as interfaces?

Comment: It means that the interface doesn't tell you the contents of the type. CGContext.h tells you that `CGContextRef` is a pointer to `struct CGContext`, but that's all you get -- there's no definition of CGContext that you can look at. It's provided in the framework, of course, but you don't get to see it, which is what makes it *opaque*.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will clear your concepts http://www.ehow.com/info_8017213_opaque-data-types.html

Comment: nice article, written in very clear format. Thanks for the nice resource